# Serialize Object in Json without the property name

Tags: c#

I am getting following json data:

```
[
  {
    "Data": [
      [915408000000,1.1789],
      [915494400000,1.179]
    ]
  }
]
```

But I don't want the property name "Data", I want this:

```
[
      [915408000000,1.1789],
      [915494400000,1.179]
]
```

Code to make the above json data:

```
    var myJsonObList = new List<MyCurrencyJsonBuilder>();
    var list = // I am getting data from sqlServer in a list;
    var myJsonObj = new MyCurrencyJsonBuilder(list);
    myJsonObList.Add(myJsonObj);
    //send response with json
    context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myJsonObList));
```

Class:

```
class MyCurrencyJsonBuilder
        {
         List<List<dynamic>> _data { get; set; }

            public MyCurrencyJsonBuilder(List<List<dynamic>> currencydata)
            {

                this._data = currencydata;
            }

            public List<List<dynamic>> Data
            {
                get { return _data; }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can use a custom Json converter. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934487/custom-json-serialization-of-class

To me, though, it seems that you are serializing an object with a Data property, when you need to serialize the Data property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json = @"
[
  {
    ""Data"": [
      [915408000000, 1.1789],
      [915494400000,1.179]
    ]
  }
]";

var jToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);
var jArray = new JArray();
foreach (var token in jToken)
{
    jArray.Add(token["Data"].Children());
}
var responseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jArray);
// responseJson = [[915408000000,1.1789],[915494400000,1.179]]
```