# NewtonSoft Json Deserializing error - Could not convert string to decimal: /Date(1490721584000-0500)/

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

In my ASP.Net MVC project, using NewtonSoft json deserializer, I'm consuming a json web service sending date in /Date()/ format. I'm receiveing json as (showing first of many array elements):

```
[
  {
    "Prop1": false,
    "Prop2": false,
    "TimeDtlList": [
      {
        "CustName": null,
        "tranDate": null,
        "startTime": "/Date(1490721584000-0500)/",
        "endTime": "/Date(1490734813000-0500)/",
      }
    ],
    "name": "Bill, Jack F.",
  }
]
```

In my code, I'm using `DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat`, however I'm still getting error:

> Could not convert string to decimal: /Date(1490721584000-0500)/. Path
>   '[0].times[0].startTime', line 1, position 337.

I'm deserializing the object using:

```
JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings{DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat};
List<Times> timesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<Times>>(text, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

and my model classes are defined as:

```
public class Times
{
    public Boolean prop1 { get; set; }
    public Boolean prop2 { get; set; }
    public List<TimeDtl> TimeDtlList { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }        
}
public class TimeDtl
{
    public String CustName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? tranDate { get; set; }
    public Decimal? startTime { get; set; }
    public Decimal? endTime { get; set; }        
}
```

How can I deserialize the time correctly?

Answer (score 1):

according to your `json` its just object of `Times` not `List<Times>`

```
string json = "{\"startTime\": \"/Date(1490721584000-0500)/\",\r\n\"endTime\": \"/Date(1490734813000-0500)/\"}";
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Times result = stuff.ToObject<Times>();
```

and you can access values like

`result.startTime`  for documentation of `ToObject` you can check this [ToObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1_1.htm)

**Edit**

so according to your new model json should be

```
var result = stuff.ToObject<List<Times>>();
```

and in your model you need to correct the type from

```
public Decimal? startTime { get; set; }
public Decimal? endTime { get; set; }
```

to

```
public DateTime? startTime { get; set; }
public DateTime? endTime { get; set; }
```

since the `startTime` and `endTime` is of type `DateTime`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt comment and my apologies for not displaying the complete json packet and model classes. I've update code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON object is giving you `startTime` and `endTime` as date-time objects but your class is expecting a decimal for both of those properties. Change your class to use `DateTime` and it should workout.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest and fastest way in such problem is to change decimal types to string and add additional properties with custom logic of getting decimal from string like:

```
public class TimeDtl
{
    public String CustName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? tranDate { get; set; }
    public string startTime { get; set; }
    public string endTime { get; set; }

    public decimal? startTimeDecimal
    {
        get
        {
            // logic of converting to decimal
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can write your own custom serializer. Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934487/custom-json-serialization-of-class).