# Is there a way to return a custom JSON structure on an object when using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, system.text.json

I am writing a class (AttributeBag) that doesn't expose any public properties. Inside, I have a list of objects (Attribute) that I manage via Get and Set methods. I want to be able to run JsonSerializer.Serialize() on the AttributeBag class and retrieve a JSON structure like below:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "x",
    "Value": "y"
  },
  {
    "Name": "x1",
    "Value": "y1"
  },
  {
    "Name": "x2",
    "Value": "y2"
  }
]
```

My Attribute and AttributeBag classes look like these:

```
public class Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class AttributeBag
{
    private readonly List<Attribute> attributes;

    public AttributeBag()
    {
        this.attributes = new List<Attribute>();
    }

    public AttributeBag Set(string name, object value)
    {
        var searchAttribute = this.attributes.Find(x => x.Name.Equals(name));

        if (searchAttribute != null)
        {
            searchAttribute.Value = value;
        }
        else
        {
            this.attributes.Add(new Attribute { Name = name, Value = value });
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Attribute Get(string name)
    {
        var searchAttribute = this.attributes.Find(x => x.Name.Equals(name));

        if (searchAttribute != null)
        {
            return searchAttribute;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AttributeNameNotFoundException(name);
        }
    }

    public object GetValue(string name)
    {
        var searchAttribute = this.attributes.Find(x => x.Name.Equals(name));

        if (searchAttribute != null)
        {
            return searchAttribute.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AttributeNameNotFoundException(name);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do something simple like this:

```
var ab = new AttributeBag();
ab.Set("x", "y");
ab.Set("x1", "y1");
ab.Set("x2", "y2");
string jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(ab);
```

I tried looking at the documentation but unsure of how to proceed with the above. Should I be using Utf8JsonWriter for this? It seems that if I use Utf8JsonWriter I would need to have a function that implements the JSON Writing and call it with ab.Serialize() for example and wouldn't need to use JsonSerializer directly. Would that be the way to go or is there a way to use JsonSerializer.Serialize?

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: To serialize json override WriteJson Method of JsonConverter class, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934487/custom-json-serialization-of-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Sushant Yelpale for the hint and link in the comments, I managed to implement the custom serialization as below.

I created a new converter class AttributeBagConverter:

```
class AttributeBagConverter : JsonConverter<AttributeBag>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override AttributeBag Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, AttributeBag value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();

        if (value.Count > 0)
        {           
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();

                writer.WritePropertyName("Name");
                writer.WriteStringValue(item.Name);

                writer.WritePropertyName("Value");
                if (double.TryParse(item.Value.ToString(), out double n))
                {
                    writer.WriteNumberValue(n);
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.WriteStringValue(item.Value.ToString());
                }

                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }           
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Then I decorated my AttributeBag class with `JsonConverter(typeof(AttributeBagConverter))`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(AttributeBagConverter))]
public class AttributeBag: IEnumerable<Attribute>
{
    private readonly List<Attribute> attributes;

    public int Count 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.attributes.Count;
        }
    }

    public AttributeBag()
    {
        this.attributes = new List<Attribute>();
    }

    public AttributeBag Set(string name, object value)
    {
        var searchAttribute = this.attributes.Find(x => x.Name.Equals(name));

        if (searchAttribute != null)
        {
            searchAttribute.Value = value;
        }
        else
        {
            this.attributes.Add(new Attribute { Name = name, Value = value });
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Attribute Get(string name)
    {
        var searchAttribute = this.attributes.Find(x => x.Name.Equals(name));

        if (searchAttribute != null)
        {
            return searchAttribute;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AttributeNameNotFoundException(name);
        }
    }

    public object GetValue(string name)
    {
        var searchAttribute = this.attributes.Find(x => x.Name.Equals(name));

        if (searchAttribute != null)
        {
            return searchAttribute.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new AttributeNameNotFoundException(name);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Attribute> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.attributes.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Calling JsonSerializer.Serialize() on the object now returns the correct JSON format that I was looking for!